# Disk partition for ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

1. I have installed Windows 7 with two partitions (C & D drives both have 60GB each)on my 160 GB HDD.  Now I want to install Ubuntu 14.4.2 on the unallocated remaining disk space.  Please tell me what should be the disk partition for installing Ubuntu on this Intel-i5 system having 4 GB RAM if I opt to install Ubuntu by selecting "something else" option.  Also let me know is there any mandatory % of disk space required/specification for allocation of `swap`,`/`,`/user`, `/home`, etc.
2. Sometimes, it happens that after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 as dual OS, the boot option menu did not show and can not log in to Windows OS. Tell me please how can I solve this issue

Comment: How big is your unallocated space?

Comment: First, try the easy install method. Ubuntu should find the unallocated space and offer to install alongside Windows as an option. If this does not work, search this site for manual partitioning advice. As for Q 2, if the problem happens you will need to provide more details.

Comment: @user68186 Un this case I suggest not splitting `/` and `/home`.

Comment: With only 40GB, just 2GB for swap and rest of space for / (root). Only if large space  may you then want separate /home or data partition(s). With 4GB of RAM you will probably not use swap but should have a little. If you wanted to hibernate then swap would have to be 4GiB or over 4GB, but hibernation when dual booting not recommended. And Ubuntu boots fast enough that hibernation does not save much, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me what should be the disk partition for installing Ubuntu

Whatever you want since we have hardly any restrictions. If you want you can have 1 massive partition named "/" or have 2 partitions 1 named "/" and 1 named "/home" for your personal data.

The only restrictions we have: you must have a partition named "/". All partitions that have system related files (ie. "/" and "/home" except for the user dirs in "/home") need to be formatted in a file system that is POSIX compliant. "ext4" is the current default.

Size can be calculated on how you use your system but 10Gb/15Gb can be enough if you use a "/home" for your personal data. If you want to use mysql for instance your "/" might need a bit more. I hardly reach 10Gb on "/" and use my system with some test databases using mysql.

> Sometimes, it happens that after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 as dual OS, the boot option menu did not show and can not log in to Windows OS. Tell me please how can I solve this issue

- Re-install grub. Example: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)
- You might also want to install "boot customizer". It is a tool to edit and view your boot settings.

Comment: Other note is partitions should not e in Windows formats such as NTFS, VAT32, etc. Use EXT4, (the default format used) or something else if you know about other Linux formats.

Comment: @user68186 good one :D added.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 60 GB total space for Ubuntu, I suggest this split:

4 GB for `swap`

The rest for `/`

It does not make any sense to have separate `/` and `/home` when there is very little space.

This is not related to Windows at all. Just a general recommendation.